# Android Save/Restore icon with transparent background in Fragment's lifecycle methods

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bitmap, facebook-android-sdk

I face the problem and I don't have an idea how to solve it.
I have an Android app with list view. Each list item have text and icon(icon load from network). I want to implement onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState in my android app. And the main purpose of this methods will be that loaded icons must save in Bundle when fragment go to back stack and restored after fragment restore.Each icon of the list item has transparent background. And when I restore the icon it has black background rather then transparent like it must be.
I have already code to save/restore the bitmaps but I can't restore the bitmap with transparent backgroun.

The code to save icon:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] iconInByte = stream.toByteArray();
outState.putByteArray("icon" + String.valueOf(i), iconInByte);
```

The code to restore icon:

```
byte[] icon = savedInstanceState.getByteArray("icon" + String.valueOf(i));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icon, 0, icon.length);
```

And few screens before and after restoring:

Before restoring:
[image]

After restoring:
[image]

Have any ideas to solve this problem?